# Nexus artifact delete command

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have uploaded the artifact to Sonatype Nexus from command line by using 
MAVEN/maven/bin/mvn -X  -e deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://maven-nexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/xyz -DrepositoryId=xyz -DgroupId=com.kumar -DartifactId=peshu -Dversion=1.0.12 -Dpackaging=war -Dfile=RIGHT.war

Now I would like to delete this version (1.0.12) from command line so that I can automate this process, what is the command I can use instead of Curl.

Answer (score 10):

Short anwser:

`curl --request DELETE --write "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" --user login:password --output /dev/null --silent http://maven-nexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/xyz/com.kumar/peshu/1.0.12`

This will delete the hole GAV from your nexus.

Note:

- The `--write "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n` option will return you the http code and the effective url used; idem the `--output /dev/null --silent` hide some verbose informations on the output,...
- I am not quite sure, but I think you need a user login with admin rights on the Nexus.

Answer (score 4):

Nexus version 2.5 has a [Remove Releases From Repository](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/scheduled-tasks.html) task.

The issue of deleting released artifacts is discussed in detail here:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20871791-Can-I-delete-releases-from-Nexus-after-they-have-been-published-

Comment: Is it possible to lanch a task via a REST request ?