# How to delete a directory from nexus using curl command

Tags: jenkins, unix, curl, nexus

I'm currently using this command to delete a specific file from a directory
and it works as expected

```
curl -s -u user_name:password  --request DELETE https://host_name/repository/Folder/artifact.py
```

I would like to delete the Folder Directory using **this** curl command but this isn't working : (

```
curl -s -u user_name:password --request DELETE https://host_name/repository/Folder
```

please help with the command to delete the directory using the curl command.

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115641/598141

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Nexus 3. You can follow this enhancement request for the feature on the project's Jira, https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11881.

The only solution seems to either delete the directory (subtree) manually using the Web UI, as implemented in https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14682.

Or write a script that will search for all files in the subtree and delete them one by one (after which the empty directories will also disappear), for example something like https://gist.github.com/kamal2222ahmed/c3d65dfac3f2bc26183e7f5e4caa51cd